# Downloaded Model Is Purple - Image Texturing

Tags: modeling, image, uv-image-editor

So I downloaded a model from a website and when I imported it to blender it came out as purple. I do know that this means that Blender is telling me that something is missing but because it is a downloaded model I can't seem to figure it out. I also downloaded the images, but there are so many textures and bump-based images that it gets complicated. Nonetheless, I could just scratch it all and start making the textures and images myself, but I just want to know if there is a shortcut. Here is the image of the downloaded model:
[image]

And here is a link to the download page (it's free): https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/woman/unity-digital-human-hs015

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you need help with the setup of the materials and the image textures you should list the names of the images and tell us how many there are.

Comment: Here is the link to the model (it's free): https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/woman/unity-digital-human-hs015 You can find the textures there. If there are complications I will just give you the images

Comment: Hello :). You need to download the "HS015.fbm.zip" folder. It contains all the required textures :).

Comment: I did I just need to know how to texture each item into the model

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  This question is getting close votes because it is too localized.  If you can edit it to make it more general-case friendly (i.e. not necessarily this specific model, but any model that has several missing image textures) it will be queued for review to be reopened.  A screenshot of one of the materials would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jachym Michal already mentioned, the Blender-friendly textures are in HS015.fbm.zip. Just extract them into a folder. In Blender, use the menu entry *File → External Data → Find Missing Files* to get the correct path.

After this, you need to fix the **transparency**, and the ***Roughness* and *Specular*** values. They are a bit messed up.

[image: use of the alpha mask]
<sup>Yes, the model comes with *Shapekeys* :-)</sup>

**Transparency**
The materials in the FBX file use the base (diffuse) color for the *Alpha* slot. That's wrong. The images have an *Alpha* mask. So just remove the wrong *Image Texture* node and plug in the `Alpha` output from the *Image Texture* into the `Alpha` slot of the *Principled BSDF* node.

In the *Material Properties > Settings* set *Blend Mode* to `Alpha Hashed`.

You need to do this for the cloth, the body, the eyes, the hair, the eyelashes, the tear line, the eye's fake AO (CC_Base_EyeOcclusion). Each eye has its own material slot.

**Roughness and Specular**
for most materials you can go with the default *Specular* value of `0.5` and adjust the *Roughness* value

- use a low *Roughness* value `0.1` and default *Specular* value `0.5` for the eyes and tear line to give them a reflection
- a little more *Roughness* `0.3` to `0.4` for teeth and the wet tongue for reflection
- increase the *Specular* value for the hair a little (`0.15`) so there is some sheen in the light
- for the skin, you can use the "MetallicAlpha" and "SpecMask" from the Textures.zip file and control with them the *Roughness* value. This way the nose holes are not shiny but black. **Note:** Use the *Alpha* output from the "MetallicAlpha" images. A *Specular* value of `0.3`-`0.4` is fine.

**Subsurface Scattering**
use a little for the skin to make it look more realistic and more "skinny". For testing, I use the "SSS" mask from Textures.zip. But I think you can use a plain color in Eevee. The body below the neck uses a plain SSS color, the arms are unchanged and have no SSS and no roughness (see the first image).

[image: skin textures]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but for some reason every time I try to hit Find Missing Files and go to the folder it says that it still cannot find the missing files. I've even tried dragging each single image in the find file box but it doesn't seem to be working. Sorry to mess up on the first instruction I hope this does work!